# junit raise InvocationTargetException

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, junit

I have made a sample by maven and spring mvc and hiberanete.
pom is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Spring3HibernateMaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>Spring3HibernateMaven</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repository.jboss.org-public</id>
            <name>JBoss repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Core utilities used by other modules. Define this if you use Spring 
            Utility APIs (org.springframework.core.*/org.springframework.util.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Expression Language (depends on spring-core) Define this if you use 
            Spring Expression APIs (org.springframework.expression.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Bean Factory and JavaBeans utilities (depends on spring-core) Define 
            this if you use Spring Bean APIs (org.springframework.beans.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) Framework (depends on spring-core, 
            spring-beans) Define this if you use Spring AOP APIs (org.springframework.aop.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Application Context (depends on spring-core, spring-expression, spring-aop, 
            spring-beans) This is the central artifact for Spring's Dependency Injection 
            Container and is generally always defined -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Various Application Context utilities, including EhCache, JavaMail, 
            Quartz, and Freemarker integration Define this if you need any of these integrations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Transaction Management Abstraction (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
            spring-aop, spring-context) Define this if you use Spring Transactions or 
            DAO Exception Hierarchy (org.springframework.transaction.*/org.springframework.dao.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JDBC Data Access Library (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, 
            spring-tx) Define this if you use Spring's JdbcTemplate API (org.springframework.jdbc.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Object-to-Relation-Mapping (ORM) integration with Hibernate, JPA, 
            and iBatis. (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context, spring-tx) 
            Define this if you need ORM (org.springframework.orm.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Object-to-XML Mapping (OXM) abstraction and integration with JAXB, 
            JiBX, Castor, XStream, and XML Beans. (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
            spring-context) Define this if you need OXM (org.springframework.oxm.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Web application development utilities applicable to both Servlet and 
            Portlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context) 
            Define this if you use Spring MVC, or wish to use Struts, JSF, or another 
            web framework with Spring (org.springframework.web.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring MVC for Servlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
            spring-context, spring-web) Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Servlet 
            Container such as Apache Tomcat (org.springframework.web.servlet.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring MVC for Portlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, 
            spring-context, spring-web) Define this if you use Spring MVC with a Portlet 
            Container (org.springframework.web.portlet.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Id @Column JPA annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate resources -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- EhCache -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>20030825.184428</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>20030825.183949</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.GA</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>Spring3HibernateMaven</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and web.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Spring3-Hibernate</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and spring.servlet.xml in file:src/main/webapps/WEB-INF/
is

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="*" />

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="classpath:jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}" p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}"
        p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />


    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>file:src/test/resources/hibernate-test.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

and jdbc.properties in classpath

```
jdbc.driverClassName= com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
jdbc.databaseurl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ContactManager
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=YOURNEWPASSWORD
```

and I have a ContactDAOImpl as bellow

```
@Repository
public class ContactDAOImpl implements ContactDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void addContact(Contact contact) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(contact);
    }

    public List<Contact> listContact() {

        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Contact")
                .list();
    }

    public void removeContact(Integer id) {
        Contact contact = (Contact) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(
                Contact.class, id);
        if (null != contact) {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(contact);
        }

    }
}
```

with ContactDAO interface

```
  public interface ContactDAO {

        public void addContact(Contact contact);

        public List<Contact> listContact();

        public void removeContact(Integer id);
    }
```

when I run the sample everything is ok but when I try to use junit

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({ "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml" })
public class ContactServiceTestImpl {

    @Autowired
    public ContactDAO contactDAO;

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Test
    public void testListContact() {

        List<Contact> result = contactDAO.listContact();
                assertNotNull(result);
    }
}
```

for testing ContactDAO when it wants to run the bellowing code in ContactDAOImpl

```
 return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Contact")
                    .list();
```

it throws InvocationTargetException exception in ReflectiveCallable

```
public abstract class ReflectiveCallable {
    public Object run() throws Throwable {
        try {
            return runReflectiveCall();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw e.getTargetException();
        }
    }

    protected abstract Object runReflectiveCall() throws Throwable;
}
```

Contact class is

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTACTS")
public class Contact {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name = "LASTNAME")
    private String lastname;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "TELEPHONE")
    private String telephone;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getTelephone() {
        return telephone;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setTelephone(String telephone) {
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see the Exception please?

Comment: it does not log any exception in tomcat

Comment: it just throw InvocationTargetException                       public abstract class ReflectiveCallable {
    public Object run() throws Throwable {
        try {
            return runReflectiveCall();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw e.getTargetException();
        }
    }

    protected abstract Object runReflectiveCall() throws Throwable;
}

Comment: where is your Contact class? Can you post that too?